# C library linkage fail with C++

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, linker, esp32

I'm using ESP32 microcontroller (C++) and trying to use "tinyexpr" library (C). I trying to link C library in my .cpp file but even with `extern "C" {}`, link can't completed. However, when I change my microcontroller file to .c, link can be completed. https://github.com/codeplea/tinyexpr

1. Here, is my real ambient (main.cpp file), trying to include tinyexpr C library.

Yes, I need to declare app_main() as extern to compile .cpp in this microcontroller ambient. I believe the problem is here, but I can't remove `extern "C"` of app_main().

```
extern "C"
{
    #include "tinyexpr/tinyexpr.h"
}

extern "C" void app_main()
{
    printf("%f\n", te_interp("5*5", 0)); /* Prints 25. */
}
```

2. Here, is my test ambient (main.c file) and work nicelly. I made this test only to know if library work in this microcontroller.

```
#include "tinyexpr/tinyexpr.h"
#include "tinyexpr/tinyexpr.c"

void app_main()
{
    printf("%f\n", te_interp("5*5", 0)); /* Prints 25. */
}
```

Output error when using main.cpp

```
/build/main/libmain.a(main.o):(.literal.app_main+0x10): undefined reference to `te_interp'
/build/main/libmain.a(main.o): In function `app_main':
/main/main.cpp:9878: undefined reference to `te_interp'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/esp-idf/make/project.mk:517: /build/esp32.elf] Error 1
```

Comment: Never include source files. Build and link with them instead.

Comment: The C code pulls in both the header for tinyexpr (`#include "tinyexpr/tinyexpr.h"`) **and** the source code (`#include "tinyexpr/tinyexpr.c"`). As another comment points out, that's not a good practice, but it's the reason that the C version doesn't get those undefined identifiers. You need to compile and link **both** files (your source file and tinyexpr.c) in order to build this project.

Comment: @some: never say never :)

Comment: When the cases where something is a good idea are astonishingly slight, never's a good enough word. By the time a programmer knows enough to find a and verify a case where including a cpp file's justified, they'll know what to do. And that's probably change the name of the file to be included.

Comment: tinyexpr.h already [contains](https://github.com/codeplea/tinyexpr/blob/master/tinyexpr.h#L30) "extern C" declarations. You just need to compile/link with tinyexpr.c. And no, the ESP32 `app_main` must not be "extern C".